# Download a text file with scp

Tags: linux, scp

I have tried

```
 scp -i ~/awscredentials/govindsinghnagarkoti.pem ubuntu@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/server/error.txt.
```

but it is giving

```
usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
       [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
       [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

How do I download the `error.txt` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't appear to have a destination file, there is no space between the source file and the `.`.

Comment: yes, and '/server/error.txt' should be 'server/error.txt'

Comment: Both source file specs are valid, I can't know where you are storing the files.